# Windows fatal exception: access violation

Tags: windows, crash, wxpython

I am currently writing a small graphical program that uses the wxpython libraries.
It's been a while that from time to time the program crashes in a random way even without needing to be made to execute an action.
I have been looking for the source of this stability problem for several days but without success, so I ask for your help;
does anyone have an idea of a possible cause of these random crashes?

Unfortunately I can't put my code here because it is too long

Here is the error in question:
`

```
Windows fatal exception: access violation


Main thread:
Current thread 0x000035a0 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\wx_env\lib\site-packages\wx\core.py", line 2262 in MainLoop
  File "d:\python\taipro\certif_generator\sensoradecertifgenerator_v2_0\cg_gui.py", line 328 in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\wx_env\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356 in compat_exec
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\wx_env\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 469 in exec_code
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\wx_env\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 613 in _exec_file
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\wx_env\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 526 in runfile
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_20792\1645014823.py", line 1 in <module>


Restarting kernel...
```

`

I looked on google with the keywords "wxpython" and "Windows fatal exception: access violation" but unfortunately I didn't find any answer to my problem.

I also tried to update my libraries but python tells me they are already up to date.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I ported a large legacy application from Python 2 to 3, everything works flawlessly except these errors popping up and crashing the whole Python process. The app I have uses threads but *all* GUI interactions happen in the main thread. For me it happens while calling Pulse() repeatedly on a wx.ProgressDialog

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I don't use this "pulse" function in my code but maybe the problem we encounter comes from the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally found the cause of my problem by myself:

I created a new blank environment and installed all the necessary packages for my code with "pip install" since then I have no more crash problems, so I guess something was wrong in my old environment or I didn't have the latest version of wxpython